# Looping not executing properly in Groovy Script

Tags: groovy

I have groovy code snippet consisting of "For Loop". Inside for loop im checking condition and in else part Im adding Thread.sleep(300000) (5 mins of waiting).

```
for(int i=0; i<8;i++) {
  if(i == 6){
     print 'Condition True'
     break;
  } else {
     try
     {
      Thread.sleep(300000)
     } catch(e) {
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
          continue;
     }
}
}
```

Case 1: After running this sample script, In the 1st iteration it is waiting for 5 mins, after that the loop is terminating itself. How can i wait for 30 mins with the intervals of 5 mins,

Case 2: If I add println 'Printing' in else part, then in 1st iteration it is waiting 5 mins after that is it waiting with 5 sec. How can i wait for 30 mins with the intervals of 5 mins.

Comment: Is your thread async? It would certainly explain why there is only one five minute sleep.

Comment: Instead of `for(int i=0; i>6;i++)` try `for(int i=0; i<6;i++)`

Comment: what exactly are you trting to do? your code doesn't make much sense ripped fromthe context...

Answer (score 0):

When I ran the same code as posted in the description, the loop did not run even once because the condition is not correct `(i>6)`. Once I fix the condition to `i<6`, then it is going into the else part for 4 times waiting for the time mentioned in sleep. After 4 times it stops because of break when `i==4`. So basically if you change the condition, it will wait for total 20min (for 5min every time). If you need to wait for total 30min and the if condition was added just to stop after 6 times then I do not see any need for the condition. You can just write as below.

```
for(int i in 1..6) {
     println "Sleeping...$i"
     try
     {
      Thread.sleep(300000)
     } catch(e) {
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
          continue;
     }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for given incorrect code, Actually I'm waiting for the node allocation, I gave the sample code for reference, when I ran with the code I'm getting the errors which I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Following is the response that I got when I ran the above with date & time in println statement. Please check if you have something else added.

Sleeping...1 06/03/2020 15:06:28
Sleeping...2 06/03/2020 15:11:28
Sleeping...3 06/03/2020 15:16:28
Sleeping...4 06/03/2020 15:21:28
Sleeping...5 06/03/2020 15:26:28
Sleeping...6 06/03/2020 15:31:28

Comment: Added @NonCPS additionally